# Regex to grab a name with varying levels. F, F+M, F+L

Tags: regex

I have a block of text that contains elements like:

```
@[30:Larry Peters]
```

Example: @[19:Sara Mas] what's the latest with the TPS report? @[30:Larry Peters] can you help out here?

I had been using: `/@\[\d+:\w+\s\w+\]/`

Problem is I've found that only matches first and last name. And not:

1. First name only
2. First, middle and lastname

Is there a way to fix this regex to match any type of name, f, f+m, f+m+l ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either allow multiple words:

`/@\[\d+:\w+(\s\w+){0,2}\]/` for up to three

or allow any amount of words and spaces:

`/@\[\d+:[\w\s]+?\]/`